# How to use JS cookies to link 3 different passwords to 3 different quizzes?

Tags: javascript, cookies, refresh

I'm new to html, css, and javascript, and I'm trying to create a webpage that can take the user on **three different pathways**. Please excuse me if my terminology isn't correct:

There is a landing page, and on the landing page is a section where you can enter in a password. The user has to enter one of three already-created passwords (This is part of a performance where I and my team would give the passwords to the audience members ahead of time.) and each password would take him/her to a different quiz to take.

How would I use **JS cookies to link the passwords to different sites?** Also, how would I make the quiz so that, **when refreshed, the user is not taken back to the beginning but stays on the same question?**

If you could provide an **explanation**, a short bit of **example code**, or even **resources** that I can use to help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Here is a video I used to help me learn about JS cookies: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqzSex_2tDc

Comment: What should happen if the user opens a new tab with the same URL? Stays on the currently open question or starts over with inputting password?

Comment: For the first time the user enters it makes no sense that the paths are stored in cookies, as the user will have no cookies stored. The first time the password can just be on the JS (this is not secure at all, it´s very easy to hack, but good enough for regular users). What you should save in the cookie is the option selected by the user, so the next time they go in you send them directly to the desired destination